# Sympy: how to solve in terms of X

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sympy

I'm simulating some voltages in sympy, and I've had problems getting the system to simplify the output. Can I ask the system not to include an unneeded variable in the output? I hoped to eliminate `V`. I ran:

```
from sympy import *
var('V1 V2 V Vout R1 R2 Rf')

solve([
    -V + V1*Rf/(Rf+R1),
    -V + (V2-Vout)*Rf/(Rf+R2),
], Vout)
# output: {Vout: -R2*V/Rf - V + V2}
```

Can I tell it to give me a result in terms of `V1`, `V2`, `R1`, `R2`, and `Rf`, but not `V`?

Note that manually removing `V` is not ideal, because not all equations are as simple as these. When I manually removed it (and decided to set `R1=R2`), I found a similar problem--

```
solve([
    Eq(V1*Rf/(Rf+R1), (V2-Vout)*Rf/(Rf+R2)),
    Eq(R1, R2)
], Vout)
# output: {Vout: (R1*V2 - R2*V1 - Rf*V1 + Rf*V2)/(R1 + Rf)}
```

Both `R1` and `R2` are included in the output. How can I make the system eliminate one? (Incidentally, eliminating `R2` will cause `R1` to cancel out.) The output should be:

```
{Vout: -V1 + V2}
```

(Note to the electronics aficionados: you may notice is a differential amplifier. I'm aware something is wrong with the initial equations. Figuring out Jupyter/sympy would really help me see what's wrong.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If V is added to the variables to solve for, it will not appear on the right:

```
solve([
    -V + V1*Rf/(Rf+R1),
    -V + (V2-Vout)*Rf/(Rf+R2),
], (Vout, V))
```

returns `{V: Rf*V1/(R1 + Rf), Vout: (-V1*(R2 + Rf) + V2*(R1 + Rf))/(R1 + Rf)}`. Access the solution for Vout with `solve(..., (Vout, V))[Vout]`

Similarly,

```
solve([
    Eq(V1*Rf/(Rf+R1), (V2-Vout)*Rf/(Rf+R2)),
    Eq(R1, R2)
], (Vout, R2))[Vout]
```

returns `-V1 + V2`.

Comment: Wow! I didn't try that because that API is clearly intended for a different use case, but that result is exactly what I want! Now, on to use this to figure out how exactly my physics is lacking...